# Am I or anyone else allowed to comment in a question of mine requesting an answer from a particular person?

Tags: discussion, comments, questions, answers

I am not talking of a [Quora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quora) style [requesting for an answer](https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-answer-request-on-Quora), but **am I or anyone else allowed to comment in a question of mine requesting an answer from a particular person?**

Example,

> Persons_name I would really appreciate an answer from you.

OR

> It is an area of expertise of Persons_name and I would appreciate an answer from him/her.

OR

> This question maybe best answered by persons_name

The reason being that particular question might be a speciality of that person.

---

The necessary assumption should be that:

- it's a **very new** question,
- that particular person is a **frequent visitor** who also sees almost every question, so there is a good chance that he/she will **probably** see the comment,
- He/she hasn't yet commented in any part of the question and its existing answers (if any).
- The Stack Exchange site is not Stack Overflow, hence the maximum questions per day is 15.

Comment: Well you can request people to turn their comment into an answer. Asking people to look at your question in another comment thread is highly frowned upon.

Comment: They won't be notified of your comment.

Comment: The comment thread is the question's thread. (like this one i.e in my question's thread itself and not its answers'). Yes, they won't be notified. But there is a big probability that they will see it.

Comment: The general workflow is more that the answerers find their way to the questions somehow, not that the questioners have to find answerers.Asking people to answer a particular question could be seen as some sort of spam.

Comment: I don't understand why am I getting downvotes. What I described is not something that never happens. Some random guy does it once a while. He/she would comment *"John Doe would be able to answer it"*. Am I supposed to flag such a comment?

Comment: Yes, you're supposed to flag such a comment.

Comment: "... requesting answer from a particular person?" - Only in Stack Overflow **Teams**, using [this button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTqM5.jpg) included in the question area (near the Tags). --- BTW: @Closers, the duplicate is about "private messaging" (for any purpose, not specifically requesting input from a number of people about the question).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They won't be notified of your comment.

So either they organically come across your question in which case the comment wasn't much use as they are already looking at your question when they came across it or, they'll never see or know about your comment at all.

In general therefore this is, at best a waste of effort. Worse, many high rep people don't really want to be pinged directly, they may have seen the question already but decided to answer some other questions instead today. We're not a 1:1 helpdesk and there are lots of people that need help.

If you want/need to draw more attention to your question, give it a bounty.

If you see such comments written by others, feel free to flag them so that moderators can delete them as they are just noise i.e. they aren't contributing to clarification of the post.